# How to sum time in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good day to all! 
I got range of cells in Excel file with values of time like "12:00" (hh:mm), which stored as plain text, without specific cells formatting. I need to sum all of cells, but i got zero, when I try SUM function.
How can I get the total sum of a range of cells in the form "**hhh:mm:ss**"?

Comment: use a formula or series of columns to tease out your hours, minutes, seconds. convert to lowest time form, in other words have all the numbers in the same unit of time. add them, sum them, then convert back into your hh:mm:ss format using formulas.

Comment: Don't store times as text. Convert them to true times (which are just numbers).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is located at `[D12:D22]`

[image]

Try this formulas:

- To convert a time in the form of text to a serial number use this formula:
  `= TIMEVALUE(D12)`
- To add time entered as number use this formula:
  `=SUM(E12:E22)` and format the cell as: `[hh]:mm:ss`
- To add time entered as text use this `formula array`:
  `= SUM( TIMEVALUE(D$12:D$22) )` and format the cell as: `[hh]:mm:ss`

[image]